# Can someone identify this coin? ΤΙΓΡΑΝΟ(Υ) (Β)ΑΣΙΛΕΩ(Σ)

Tags: identification, numismatics

Can someone please identify this coin? I would really appreciate it if you could tell me how old it is and what era it belongs to?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/up4S3.jpg)
[image: coin]

Answer (score 17):

It looks to be a version of a coin representing the Armenian king [Tigranes II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigranes_the_Great), with the [Tyche of Antioch](http://www.livius.org/articles/concept/tyche-of-antioch/) on the flip side. You can read about the history at the above wiki link.

[image]

Above image from [The Melammu Project](http://www.aakkl.helsinki.fi/melammu/database/gen_html/a0000054.php)

Some more versions can be seen [here](https://www.coinarchives.com/a/results.php?search=Tigranes+II)

An article [here](https://academic.oup.com/astrogeo/article/45/4/4.6/1746011/Halley-s-comet-of-87-BC-on-the-coins-of-Armenian) actually theorizes that the star symbol on the crown may represent Halley's Comet.

Comment: Yes, the (Greek) letters in the coin in question seem to agree with your coin: ΤΙΓΡΑΝΟ(Υ) and (Β)ΑΣΙΛΕΩ(Σ) with the letters in parentheses not clearly visible. (ΤΙΓΡΑΝΟΥ ΒΑΣΙΛΕΩΣ meaning: ***King Tigranes'***)